# Need of page factory in page object model

Tags: java, design-patterns, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

Can anyone please explain what is the need of pagefactory in page object model.

Eg. We use below code for initializing the page object class.

```
LoginPage loginPage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, LoginPage.class);
```

Why can't we use

```
LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);
```

Similarly while returning new page in each page object method we use

```
return new PageFactory.initElements(driver, HomePage.class);
```

why should it not be

```
return new HomePage(driver);
```

Please help me in understanding PageFactory, as I am new to page object pattern. I am thinking we can still manage without using PageFactory.

Comment: you can manage without using PageFactory. Read about design patterns.

Answer (score 4):

You can, in fact, use the page object pattern without using the `PageFactory` class. The page object pattern simply abstracts your business logic away from the physical structure of your pages. What the `PageFactory` class gives you is the ability to use annotations to automatically find the elements on the page without resorting to explicit `findElement` calls. It lets you write code like this:

```
public class LoginPage {
  @FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "user")
  private WebElement userNameTextBox;

  @FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "password")
  private WebElement passwordTextBox;

  public void fillLoginDetails(String userName, String password) {
    userNameTextBox.sendKeys(userName);
    passwordTextBox.sendKeys(password);
  }
}
```

Note that there are no explicit `findElement` calls here. Using the `PageFactory` allows you to write this code more cleanly and eliminates some boilerplate code. The same thing could be accomplished by using `findElement` in your page objects to locate the appropriate elements. It's a stylistic choice.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. So since we are not using driver instance in LoginPage or in any page objects while using page factory, where do we write our custom waits etc (or any actions which involves driver object)? Whether these waits should be a part of page object or part of my tests?

Answer (score 2):

The `PageFactory` injects `WebElement`s defined in your page object using the `WebDriver` you provide.

The documentation of [PageFactory](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageFactory) says:

> The PageFactory relies on using sensible defaults: the name of the field in the Java class is assumed to be the "id" or "name" of the element on the HTML page.

So you can just define a field of type `WebElement` with the id or name of an `WebElement` and the `PageFactory` takes care that it will be available.

> I am thinking we can still manage without using PageFactory.

Yes you can. If you don't use the `PageFactory` you must lookup the `WebElement`s using the `WebDriver` api, e.g.

```
WebElement searchBox = driver.findElement(By.id("q"));
```

But you can also annotate a field with `@FindBy`, `@FindBys` or `@FindAll` , e.g.

```
@FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "q")
private WebElement searchBox;
```

> I am new to page object pattern

A page object is an encapsulation of some web page. It's api provides a user-like access to the web page and hides the implementation details of a page (web elements, ids, etc.). Thus you can write your tests in a way a user would describe the tests.

For example

```
 @Test
 public void googleSearch(){
     WebDriver driver = ....;

     GooglePage google = GooglePage.open(driver);
     SearchResultPage searchResult = google.search("stackoverflow");
     SearchResult firstResult = searchResult.getResult(0); // first result

     Assert.assertEquals("Stack Overflow", firstResult.getTitle());
     ...
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. So since we are not using driver instance in LoginPage or in any page objects while using page factory, where do we write our custom waits etc (or any actions which involves driver object)? Whether these waits should be a part of page object or part of my tests?

Comment: I think the waits should be part of the page object. E.g. if the page contains a component whose content is loaded by an ajax call than your test should get a reference to it not until it is loaded. E.g. `TableComponent tc = page.getResultTable()`. This also means that you need the web driver in the pages and components. Normally I use `LoadableCompoent` to implement pages and components on pages: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/LoadableComponent

Comment: Thanks Rene for your valuable feedback

Answer (score 0):

I see that you use java for selenium. You should take a look at the Arquillian-Graphene framework. It is an extesnion. So it will not mess up with your existing framework.

Main aim of using Arquillian framework is - you do not need Page Factory. It has nice set of annotations to inject the page object model at run time.

For ex: I create a page object for Google as shown here.

```
public class Google {

    @Drone
    private WebDriver driver;

    public void goTo(){
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
    }

    public boolean isAt(){
        return driver.getTitle().equals("Google");
    }
}
```

In my testng/junit,

```
@RunAsClient
public class GoogleSearchTest extends Arquillian{

    @Page
    Google google;


    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void launchGoogle(){

        google.goTo();
        Assert.assertTrue(google.isAt());

    }

}
```

Did you notice?  @Drone - automatically injects the browser instance. @Page automatically creates a Google page object instance.

Check here for more info:

http://www.testautomationguru.com/arquillian-graphene-page-fragments/